# Duplicado de peticiones

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
(function(){
                $('a').on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    $.get(url, function(html){
                    $('.main').empty().append(html);
                    });
                });
            })();
```

Tengo esta función para evitar el reload con postback, solo cargo unos cuantos elementos dentro del div "main". Seguramente a causa de no ser la forma más óptima de cumplir esta labor la petición se duplica cada vez que doy click a un link. aumenta progresivamente además, al primer click duplica 2 veces, al segundo 3, al tercero 9 etc...

¿Alguna solución u otra función que me ayude a hacer esto? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Ya solucionaron mi problema, sin embargo si creen que hay una mejor función, agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: intentastes colocarle antes un $('a').off("click")?

Comment: Sí bro, eso lo solucionó! muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo marcar la respuesta?

Comment: OK dejame hacerte una respuesta y me puntuas vale? gracias que bueno que se te soluciono

Comment: Listo ya me puedes tildar como correcta mi respuesta, en la respuesta hay unas flechitas arriba y abajo, debajo de dichas flechitas hay como una especie de tilde, le das allí, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca antes de `$('a').on('click', function(e){` un `$('a').off("click")`, tu còdigo quedaria así:

```
(function(){

  $('a').off("click")
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(url, function(html){
      $('.main').empty().append(html);
    });
  });

})();
```

Comment: Si lo pones encima no funciona, si lo pones dentro sí.

Comment: dentro del evento click?